# {{> afQuickField name='locationType' Optionvalue="locationType "}}

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mongodb, meteor

I want to add and edit the search menu select from the dropdown

from {{> afQuickField name='locationType' Optionvalue="locationType "}}

Comment: Can you please specify your problem? Something not showing? Errors thrown? Please also add the full `autoForm` or `quickForm` code, the schema that is used and AutoForm.hooks, if used. Otherwise this needs to get closed, since nobody will understand what you are actually asking for.

Comment: Please also consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.